Is this proof for problem 3.19 in Baby Rudin correct?
Problem 3.19 in Baby Rudin, states

Associate to each sequence $a=\{a_n\}$, in which $a_n$ is $0$ or $2$, the real number $$x(a) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{3^n}$$ Prove that the set of all $x(a)$ is precisely the Cantor set.

I wrote a proof for this problem, but I am not sure if it is correct and there is a part (in bold) which I am not sure is justified.
My proof: 
Lemma 1  The left and right endpoints of the cantor set can be expressed by $$\left[\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{a_n}{3^n} + \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{0}{3^n}\right] \text{ and } \left[\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{a_n}{3^n} + \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{2}{3^n}\right]$$ respectively for some $N\in\mathbb{N}$. 
Left Endpoints:
WTS that by dividing each $C_n$ in half, when left endpoint $x$ is on left side, $a_1 = 0$ when it is on right side, $a_1=2$, then by taking the half that $x$ is on and dividing again, $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ can be found through this process. The rest, $a_{n+1}, ... =0$. So, for example, for $C_4$ and the left endpoint $a=\frac{2}{27}$. "a" is on the left side of $C_4$, so $a_1=0$, of that side, it is again on the left so $a_2=0$, than it is on the right $a_3=2$, than it is on the left half of that section, $a_4=0$. $0+0+\frac{2}{3^3}+0 = \frac{2}{27}$.
Base case: $C_1 = [0,\frac{1}{3}] \cup [\frac{2}{3},1]$. Clearly, $0= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{0}{3^n}$ and $ \frac{2}{3} = \frac{2}{3} + \sum_{n=2}^\infty 0$ 
Inductive step: Assume that each left endpoint $x$ in $C_n$ has this property where a sequence of $\{a_n\}$ can be found by the dividing process. Consider $C_{n+1}$. If $x$ is carried over from $C_n$ than the formula is the same, with $a_{n+1} = 0$ since $x$ is on the left half of the original interval in $C_n$. If $x$ is "new'', than $a_{n+1} = 2$ since it is on the right side of the split interval, so $\frac{2}{3^{n+1}}$ is added compared to the process to get to the the left side of the split interval which is carred over from $C_n$. 
Right Endpoints:
Similarly, for right endpoints in $C_n$ the exact same process of assigning values to $a_n$ is done except now for $k>n$, $a_n=2$.
Theorem 1  Problem 3.19 
$\implies$ If $x$ is an endpoint of $\mathcal{C}$, than it can be expressed as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{3^n}$ by the lemma above. If $x$ is not an endpoint than it is a limit point of a sequence of endpoints (since $\mathcal{C}$ is perfect), $\{s_n\}$ where $s_k$ is the left endpoint in the interval containing $x$ in $C_k$. So $\{s_n\} = \{\frac{a_1}{3}, \frac{a_1}{3} + \frac{a_2}{3^2}, ...\}$. This sequence of partial sums converges to $x$ so that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{3^n} = x$. 
$\impliedby$ For x in the set of all $x(a)$, if it can be expressed as $$\left[\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{a_n}{3^n} + \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{0}{3^n}\right] \text{ or } \left[\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{a_n}{3^n} + \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{2}{3^n}\right]$$ than $x$ is an endpoint of $\mathcal{C}$, since these sums provide a roadmap to pinpoint $x$ by dividing up $C_N$. Let $\{a_n\}$ be the sequence that describes $x$. If $x$ cannot be expressed like in the formulas above than construct a sequence made of the terms in $\{a_n\}$, $\{\frac{a_1}{3}, \frac{a_1}{3}+ \frac{a_2}{3^2}, \frac{a_1}{3}+ \frac{a_2}{3^2} + \frac{a_3}{3^3},...\}$ which converges to $x$. But since each term in the sequence is a left endpoint of $\mathcal{C}$ that means there exists a sequence in $\mathcal{C}$ which converges to $x$, but since $\mathcal{C}$ is compact, $x\in\mathcal{C}$
* I know that the sequence in bold converge to $x$, but am I able to assume that there exists a sequence $\{a_n\}$ that satisfies this? Since I am basically generating the sequence $\{a_n\}$ as $\{s_n\}$ is being created. 

"Prove that the set of all $x(a)$ is precisely the Cantor set described in Sec. 2.44." : In general, when posting a question on MathSE, it is a good idea to proofread your post to see how MathSE reviewers are going to react.  Here, it is clear that you should provide a specification, near the start of your posted question, for "the Cantor set described in Sec. 2.44", whatever that is.

Besides my first comment, I have mixed reactions to your posted question.  On the one hand, I think that the work that you have shown is outstanding.  On the other hand, you are asking MathSE reviewers to review your work line by line, looking for any and all flaws.  You will get a much more positive reaction from MathSE reviewers if you highlight the exact lines, where you have taken a step that you are unsure of, and if, for each highlighted line, you explain what is causing your uncertainty.

Thank you for your feedback! I will try to implement your comments so the question is clearer.

What do you mean by "as ${s_n}$ is being created"?  ... or going about it another way, are you comfortable with saying the sequence ${C_n}$ exists?

Because, I think that as I am choosing the left endpoints that converges to x, I am choosing {a_1, a_2,...}, I am not taking these terms from a full sequence, I am basically adding on terms to {a_n} as I go on so I am not sure if it makes sense to say that there exists a {a_n} such that the infinite sum converges to x. Also, by saying {C_n} exists, do you mean a sequence of sets whose infinite intersection is the cantor set?
